# Which tool should I use in Alteryx to find values and add new column

Tags: formula, iif, alteryx

I got stuck at this for a long time and couldn't find answer elsewhere.
Below is my data:

```
Market  Start    Type(0 or 1)
  A       1
  A       2
  A       4
  A       6
  A      10
  A       2
  B       2
  B       4
  B       6
  B       8
  B       4
  B       9
  C       1
  C       4
  C       7
  C       3
  C       9
  C      11
  C      12
```

And I want to complete the Type column based on following conditions:

If Market is A and Start is 1,2,3, then Type is 1, otherwise 0

If Market is B and Start is 2,4,5, then Type is 1, otherwise 0

If Market is C and Start is 4,6,9, then Type is 1, otherwise 0

In Alteryx, I tried using the formula tool three times:

`IIF ( [Market]="A" && ([Start] in (1,2,3),"1","0")
 IIF ( [Market]="B" && ([Start] in (2,4,5),"1","0")
 IIF ( [Market]="C" && ([Start] in (4,6,9),"1","0")`
 
But the third `IIF` function overwrites the previous two. Is there any other tools in Alteryx that can do what I want to do? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It evaluates to False and places a zero for any market <> "C"... try a single Formula tool with:

```
IF [Market]="A" THEN
    IIF([Start] in (1,2,3),"1","0")
ELSEIF [Market]="B" THEN
    IIF([Start] in (2,4,5),"1","0")
ELSEIF [Market]="C" THEN
    IIF([Start] in (4,6,9),"1","0")
ENDIF
```

This should eliminate overlap.